# How to graceful shutdown an express docker app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I recently watched a Docker course where the teacher explained that for a container to close correctly the error code must be 0, the problem is that my container ends its process with a code 137.

Therefore I have been looking and trying some way to make the exit code 0 but I have not been able to.

index.js:

```
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello, Express!");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "/usr/src/"]

WORKDIR /usr/src/

RUN npm install

COPY [".", "/usr/src/"]

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

To use this container I did:

```
docker build -t express .
```

Then

```
docker run --name app -p 5000:3000 -d express
```

To inspect the process of app I did:

```
docker exec app ps -ef
```

Output:

```
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  1 11:40 ?        00:00:00 node index.js
root          14       0 50 11:40 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef
```

This is the output after "docker stop app", the container wait 10 second or so before stop

This is the output after docker ps -l:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                        PORTS     NAMES
7e7916725120   express   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   24 seconds ago   Exited (137) 10 seconds ago             app
```

I uploaded the repo in case you need it:

https://github.com/ivandez/express-so

Comment: You can handle events like `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` using `process.on(...` and exit gracefully. But unfortunately `docker stop` sends the `SIGKILL` event which I don't think can be handled. Exit code 137 means that the process was killed using `SIGKILL`. You can specify a signal to send on `docker stop` using `-s <signal>`. If you're willing to do that, you can use SIGTERM. Then you can handle it in Node and exit with code 0.

Comment: docker stop always sends first SIGTERM to stop a container and after a certain time Docker will send SIGKILL. EDIT: source: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/stop/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you do:
`docker stop $(docker ps -q -l)` or something like `docker stop abcedef` after `docker ps -a` docker stop will initially will send a `SIGTERM`. You need to handle this on the Node.js side:

```js
process.on("SIGTERM", function(code_signal_error){
    process.exit(0) //or whatever you want
})
```

For me exit code of Node is rarely significant, so I normally do something like:

```js
[`exit`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGINT`, `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2`, `uncaughtException`, `SIGTERM`].forEach(function(evt){
        process.on(evt, this);
    }, once(
        function(code_signal_error){
            //decide what to do here. Terminate workers etc.
            //do not forget to call process.exit(0) or whatever value makes sense to you.
        }
    ));
```

`once` above is an implementation that returns a function that executes only once, you can find many implementations, I use a custom one. The reason is docker stop will send  `SIGKILL` after some time if `SIGTERM` did not take effect.